# Getting "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth, access-token

I am trying to create a token using authorization_code grant type.
I can see a parameter called code. I am not sure what is the value to be given for this.

Here is the screenshot

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUQoI.png)

Please help me to pass the correct value for the parameter code.

Comment: refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token#get-azure-ad-tokens-by-using-a-web-browser-and-curl the value of the code will be the output of the `/authorize` endpoiint which you need to make first

Comment: I did that. It is giving response as <title>Sign in to your account</title>

Comment: "code" is receivied from /authorize endpoint and need to be passed to /token endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

From the screenshot shared by you it seems you are trying to do a call for token to the Graph API using the implicit flow.

For the same you need to send the request in the following format containing the following fields only:

grant_type : client_credentials

scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

client_secret : XXXXXXXXXXX

client_id : XXXXXXXXXXXX

This is a POST request that needs to be sent.

URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant ID/oauth2/v2.0/token

Also send this request body in form-data format or x-www-form-urlencoded.

Also the latest issue with the Graph API's is the support for TLS V1.0 and V1.1 has ended. So please ensure that the request is made on TLS V1.2.

Comment: He is using Auth code flow not ROPC.

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu : My bad. You are right.